# Using a private array in a public static void method

Tags: c#

I have a class where I'm supposed to have a private array.

```
private int[] array = new int[5];
```

and I'm supposed to have a public method where I put data into the array but I'm unsure of how to make it work properly.

```
public static void method(int a, int b)
{
     `array[a-1] = b;`
}
```

I've tried this and it gives me an error saying an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Class.array'. 
Can someone help me figure out how to deal with this problem?

Comment: can you show the whole code, it looks like it cannot find array?

Comment: Since your method is static, you can only access other static methods and fields. Your array needs to be static  if your method is static.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access instance fields from a static method. You will need

```
private int[] array = new int[5];

public void method(int a, int b) 
{  
    array[a-1] = b; 
}
```

or debatably

```
private static int[] array = new int[5];

public static void method(int a, int b) 
{  
    array[a-1] = b; 
}
```

or you could use an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/)

```
private int[] array = new int[5];

public int this[int i]
{
   get { return array[i]; }
   set { array[i] = value; }
}
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

> A static class is basically the same as a non-static class, but there
> is one difference: a static class cannot be instantiated. In other
> words, you cannot use the new keyword to create a variable of the
> class type. Because there is no instance variable, you access the
> members of a static class by using the class name itself.

**Static Members**

> A non-static class can contain static methods, fields, properties, or
> events. The static member is callable on a class even when no instance
> of the class has been created. The static member is always accessed by
> the class name, not the instance name. Only one copy of a static
> member exists, regardless of how many instances of the class are
> created. Static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields
> and events in their containing type, and they cannot access an
> instance variable of any object unless it is explicitly passed in a
> method parameter.

Comment: Wow thank you I guess I don't really understand what the static means. What difference does it make in an array?

Comment: you may also access private members of class from static method if you have an instance of your class in static method, like: `public static void Method() { new MyClass().array = new int[6]; }`

Comment: @vasily.sib Someone would be failing my code review with that code, and asked to recommit ;)

Answer (score 1):

Static methods or variables belong to the class itself (rather than a specific instance of the class). Every instance of your class will have its own array. That static method has no way of knowing what instance to use to access the array. If you need to access instance (non-static) variables, you need to specify an instance of the class.

If you don't want to create an instance of your class, you could make the array static:

```
private static int[] array = new int[5];

public static void method(int a, int b)
{
    array[a - 1] = b;
}
```

If you don't want to make the array static, you'll have to create an instance.

You could make the method an instance method:

```
class MyClass
{
    private int[] array = new int[5];

    public static void method(int a, int b)
    {
        myClass.array[a - 1] = b;
    }
}

MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.method(1,2);
```

Or you could create a static variable with an instance of the class:

```
class MyClass
{
    private static MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    private int[] array = new int[5];

    public static void method(int a, int b)
    {
        myClass.array[a - 1] = b;
    }
}
```

The best approach would depend on you're actually trying to do.